# Paging through inequality query on multiple properties

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have a list of contacts in the datastore holding a givenName and familyName property.
I can search for a list of contacts for which the 'givenName' starts with a given query parameter. I do it like this with Objectify4 :

```
    Query<Contact> query = txn().consistency(Consistency.STRONG).load().type(Contact.class).ancestor(ancestor);
    if (criteria.getSearchString() != null) {
        query = query.filter(SEARCH_GIVEN_NAME + " >= ", criteria.getSearchString().toUpperCase());
        query = query.filter(SEARCH_GIVEN_NAME + " <= ", criteria.getSearchString().toUpperCase() + SENTINEL);

    }
    query = query.limit(criteria.getPageSize()).offset(criteria.getStartIndex());
```

But a good user experience requires a simultaneous search for contacts on 'givenName' OR 'familyName' starting with the text entered in the search box.

I cannot combine this search in one datastore query (I think). So I will have to execute two queries both with a offset and limit.

My only idea so far :

- Suppose a request for results 150-200 for search term = 'ab%'.
- Query for givenName starting with 'ab' with limit 200;
- Query for familyName starting with 'ab' with limit 200;
- Combine both results in one sorted result list
- Offset into the combined result to find 150-200.

A subsequent request for the same search term but offset 200-250 would require to repeat the whole search but with limit 250 on both queries.

This feels terribly inefficient (and costly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easier solution is to put both given name and family name into a list property, and perform your inequality comparison on that. This will return any entry where any item from the list property satisfies your criteria.

Comment: Ok, I have to try this ... So i create a list property List<String> names which I populate with uppercase values of givenName and familyName everytime I store/update a contact. What would the query look like then if I want to search for "startsWith" in any value of the list ? Thx !!

Comment: @koma Correct. The query would look the same as your existing range query on given name.

Comment: Any idea how to apply paging on such queries?